# WSFederation & Manual ClaimsIdentity with AppPool recycles

Tags: c#, identity, claims-based-identity, ws-federation

I have an application that needs to support both Federation (IdP-Initiated) as well as manual authentication (standard username/password form). As such I am using .NET v4.5 System.Identity to make the application claims aware.

The issue we are seeing in dev is that anytime an AppPool recycle happens (like a recompile) and we reload the page or take any other action we get an error trying to access any of our custom claims. It's as if the user is ***still authenticated, but our custom claims are totally gone***. In order to keep working, we need to close all instances of the browser and login again. This can obviously happen in the wild and is something we cannot have happen (horrible end user experience).

*Is there something we are doing wrong or a way that we can trap/detect this condition and force the user to log back in again?*

**Background**

In the case of a manual login, we build a CustomClaimsIdentity instance that gets passed into a new ClaimsPrincipal which is then used to create a new SessionSecuirytToken instance and then written out as follows:

```
var claims = CustomClaimsAuthenticationManager.BuildClaimsList( user );
var identity = new UniversalIdentity( claims, AuthenticationTypes.Password );
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal( identity );
var token = new SessionSecurityToken( principal, TimeSpan.FromMinutes( user.Customer.SessionExp ?? 120 ) );
var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie( token );
```

In the case of Idp-Initiated logins, we handle the *FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignedIn* event and perform checks to validate the supplied claims as well as build up the custom claims our app adds to the identity the same way we do for manual authentication.

Comment: I've narrowed this down a little further and it appears that one of my static helper classes is trying to access the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` which is just an `IPrincipal`, not a `ClaimsPrincipal`. Is there a way to make the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` object into a `ClaimsPrincipal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely cast an `IPrincipal` to `ClaimsPrincipal`:

```
ClaimsPrincipal cp = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
```